# Code Coverage: Best practice on excluding non-testable code

Tags: unit-testing, oop, tdd, code-coverage

We are currently discussing how to define our goals on code coverage in a C# project (this question is not limited to C# though). On the way, we found that we should exclude some code from being counted towards the code coverage. The most obvious are the tests themselves, as they have 100% coverage and should not influence the average. But there are also classes that are wrappers for system calls we need to be able to create mocks. They are untestable, as we don't want to test system libraries. The code is calculated towards the coverage though and makes it hard to move across the 90% mark.

We do not want to lie at ourselves by excluding every piece of code that is untested, which makes it fairly easy to walk towards 100%.

Is there any reference, article or discussion on this topic with experience in this area? We would like to explore the different views on this topic that may help us finding and developing our definition for "testable code".

Comment: Your question is off topic, but I can tell you than you don't need to overthink all this. Just write code and unit/integration tests to verify that the code does what is supposed to do. Simply put: Just do it (tm) . You'll learn more from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Code coverage isn't a terribly useful metric. It's helpful in giving management and onboarding developers a general idea of how much you value testing, but concerning yourself about it any more is pedantic and might actually serve to distract you from writing meaningful tests.

This is my opinion, [but it is not an isolated one](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=code%20coverage%20considered%20harmful)

Don't worry about coverage, define a policy in terms of what your goals are, be clear and concise, make sure everyone is on the same page about the importance of unit testing, and have a code review process in place.

You don't need a tool, just some human intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage is not a metric for how complete your test suite is, but (if all all) how incomplete it is. A high test coverage might be totally meaningless, depending on how your code coverage tool measures it.

To get a better picture which parts of your code need more tests, I would separate the code with the means of the programming language. Any sane code coverage tool should be able to show the result for these separately. Depending on how your application is structured, you can put the untestable code (i.e. the test suite itself, adapter code like "wrappers for system calls", controllers, UI elements, etc.) in separate namespaces or even separate assemblies.

The Java folks can replace "namespace" with "package" and "assembly" with "jar" in the paragraph above.